# Listview items are in wrong order and constantly changing order

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I have Favorites fragment and FavoritesListAdapter. In PlayRadioFragment, radio can be added favorite list with button. When I do that, Favorites listview populating in wrong order. And radio-name and radio-play-link are not matching correctly. Same as the remove favorites button. I guess this is happening because of getting key-values with HashMap. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

**add_favorites_button in PlayRadioFragment :**

```
add_favorites_button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_favorites_button);
        add_favorites_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS_", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(radio_name, radio_name);
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences settings_2 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS_2",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor_2 = settings_2.edit();
        editor_2.putString(radio_play_link, radio_play_link);

        editor_2.commit();

        }

        });
```

**And key-values are getting in FavoritesFragment and sending to FavoriteListAdapter :**

```
final List<String> radio_name_list = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> radio_name_list_key = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> radio_link_list = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> radio_link_list_key = new ArrayList<>();

        String radio_name = "";
        String radio_name_key = "";
        String radio_link = "";
        String radio_link_key = "";

        Map<String, ?> allEntries = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS_",0).getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        radio_name_key = entry.getKey();
        radio_name_list_key.add(radio_name_key);
        radio_name = entry.getValue().toString();
        radio_name_list.add(radio_name);
        }

        Map<String, ?> allEntries_2 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS_2",0).getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries_2.entrySet()) {
        radio_link_key = entry.getKey();
        radio_link_list_key.add(radio_link_key);

        radio_link = entry.getValue().toString();
        radio_link_list.add(radio_link);
        }



        ListView listView_favorites = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_favorites);
        adapter_2 = new FavoritesListAdapter(getActivity(), radio_name_list, radio_name_list_key, radio_link_list, radio_link_list_key);
        listView_favorites.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        PlayRadioFragment fragment= new PlayRadioFragment();
        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        bundle.putString("radio_play_links", radio_link_list.get(position));
        bundle.putString("radio_name", radio_name_list.get(position));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
        });
```

And FavoriteListAdapter, related radio and link is removing with remove button on list elements  :

```
public class FavoritesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String > {

    private Activity context;
    private List<String> radioName;
    private List<String> radio_links;
    private List<String> radio_links_key;
    private List<String> radioname_key;


    public FavoritesListAdapter(Activity context,List<String> radioName, List<String> radioname_key, List<String> radio_links, List<String> radio_links_key ) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_favorites_listview, radioName);

        this.context=context;

        this.radio_links_key= radio_links_key;
        this.radio_links= radio_links;
        this.radioName=radioName;
        this.radioname_key= radioname_key;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View r= convertView;
        FavoritesViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (r == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater= context.getLayoutInflater();
            r= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_favorites_listview,null,true);
            viewHolder = new FavoritesViewHolder(r);
            r.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else {
            viewHolder = (FavoritesViewHolder) r.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.row_tv_favorites_radio_name.setText(radioName.get(position));
        viewHolder.row_img_favorites_radio_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_logo_renkli);

        viewHolder.button_remove_from_favorites_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.remove(radioName.get(position));
                editor.remove(radioname_key.get(position));
                editor.commit();

                SharedPreferences settings_2 = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_2",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor_2 = settings_2.edit();
                editor_2.remove(radio_links.get(position));
                editor_2.remove(radio_links_key.get(position));
                editor_2.commit();

                radioName.remove(getItem(position));
                //  notifyDataSetChanged();

                FavoritesFragment.adapter_2.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return r;

    }

    class FavoritesViewHolder {
        TextView row_tv_favorites_radio_name;
        TextView row_tv_favorites_listener_numbers;
        ImageView row_img_favorites_radio_icon;
        Button button_remove_from_favorites_list;
        FavoritesViewHolder(View v) {
            row_tv_favorites_radio_name= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_radio_name_favorites);
            row_tv_favorites_listener_numbers = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_listener_numbers_favorites);
            row_img_favorites_radio_icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_radio_icon_favorites);
            button_remove_from_favorites_list = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove_favorites_from_list_button);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Change 

 radioName.remove(position);
 notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You can use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `Map`. `LinkedHashMap` keep your order.

Comment: do you think only problem is using map?

Comment: Is there a way to convert Map to LinkedHashMap?

Comment: instead of doing this lengthy process and then using four lists why don't you use a custom list with radioName and radioLink??